# Queue for more producer (thread) single consumer (thread)

Tags: c#, queue

I'm trying to find solution for more threads writing to a queue and a single thred is reading from it.

I found `ConcurrentQueue` it has `TryDequeue(T)` that is thread safe but I'm not sure if `Enqueue(T)` is thread safe too when writing to the queue from more threads.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the whole point of the concurrent collections is that they're thread-safe. It's fine to write to `ConcurrentQueue<T>` from multiple threads.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netstandard-1.6):

> All public and protected members of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.